# Delphi SQL DateTime2(5) Fraction Truncated

Tags: sql, delphi, datetime2

Got one Table with DateTime2(5) field . It looks like this :

```
2021-09-07 10:54:14.97317
```

Now I setup FDConnection with one FDQuery . I get the Column back as TSQLTimeStamp.
Now I try this :

```
  Label2.Caption:=FDQuery1lastmodzeit.Value.Fractions.ToString;
```

and I only get 973 back .

Using SQL 2012 , and it's SQL SERVER NATIVE CLIENT 11.0 .

Comment: I believe Delphi only supports milliseconds (1/1000 second), so any values beyond that is lost.

Comment: Using DateTime2(3) is one option to keep things consistent between what Delphi supports and what is stored in the database. Nanoseconds is really only needed when  debugging or performance logging. Everything else usually stops at milliseconds.  For example Javascript